# Temporarily block other users from network printer

Tags: network-printer, access-control

I found where someone else asked this question [here](http://bytes.com/topic/networking/answers/821590-possible-termporarily-lock-other-users-out-network-printer), but they did not get a working answer.  We have a printer that is shared. It has it's own network card, so we all have equal access to it. (none of our computers owns it) One of our users needs to print on specialty paper and we need to be sure not to print when that paper is in the printer. Our current method is "Hey, don't print anything right now!" Obviously this method is not preferred because it does not enforce itself.  :-)

I think all our PCs are running Win7 Home. The printer in question is an HP Laserjet 2200.
Is there a way that we can make this happen?

Comment: I would try submitting a job and then pause it. This would block many Linux/CUP-based printing systems. Depending on the firmware of your printer, this may stop it from printing as well.

Comment: If you continue to treat this printer as basically a pear to pear setup, without a print server, then there really isn't anything you can do.

Comment: @Zoredache, can you elaborate on this? How can I treat it differently, and in so doing, how can I allow one user to exercise some authority over it?